# Constructing a custom login form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, login

I'm attempting to use this tutorial [WordPress AJAX Login Without a Plugin – The Right Way](http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/#comment-4400) by Natko Hasic to build a login, registration and forgot password forms that handle everything, including error messages with AJAX. The differences between the tutorial and my project are... I don't want to do it in a popup and I'm doing it in a plugin not in the root theme folder.

Here's what code I do have...

The code in the page template:

```
<form name="login_form" id="login_form" class="login_form" action="" method="post">
    <p class="status"></p>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </p>

    <button name="submit" id="submit" class="btn"><?php _e("Sign in", "shorti"); ?></button>
    <a class="lost" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>">Lost your password?</a>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>

</form>
```

The code running in my main plugin .php file:

```
 <?php // The php script I'm trying to run

    add_action( 'init', 'ajax_login_init' );
    function ajax_login_init() {

        wp_register_script( 'ajax-login-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login-script' );

        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'redirecturl' => home_url(),
            'loadingmessage' => __( 'Sending user info, please wait...' )
        ));

        // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
    }

    // Check if users input information is valid
    function ajax_login() {
        // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    //Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
        $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
        $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
        $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user_signon )) {
        echo json_encode( array( 'loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__( 'Wrong username or password!' )));
    } else {
        echo json_encode( array( 'loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...' )));
    }

    die();
}
```

My `ajax-login-script.js` file contents:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login_form').on('#submit', function(e){
        $('form#login_form p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login_form #username').val(), 
                'password': $('form#login_form #password').val(), 
                'security': $('form#login_form #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login_form p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I'm not at all familiar with AJAX nor JS so any light you can shed on the matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: @eskimo: If you submit the form with empty forms or invalid data it just reloads the page and if I input the correct data it also reloads the page still showing the login form instead of the pages actual information. Like I said this is basically my first time trying to work with JS/AJAX... so I have no clue where to even start looking to change things. Thanks

Comment: I've didn't read the complete tutorial but the first thing I notice is that your form action is empty (`action=""`) and in the tutorial they define `action="login"`. Seems to me that's a crucial thing to fix.

Comment: @eskimo: yeah, I had put it in there but when I used the form it would redirect me to my current page with an extension of `/login` which returns a `404 page error`. Not sure if that would be considered progress or not :P

Comment: The 404 is normal since the page login doesn't exist. It shouldn't go to that page but submit the form. I've catched another error, which is crucial as well. In `ajax-login-script.js` you have `$('form#login_form').on('#submit', function(e)`. Remove the '`#`' before submit. And make sure that `action="login"` is still set on the form code.

Comment: @eskimo: Finally got back around to this part of the project and changed what you pointed out and it all works great! Thank you ever so much!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @eskimo I was able to get this working and figured I share an answer for any of those trying to do the same!

In the `ajax-login-script.js` file all I had to do was change this `$('form#login_form').on('#submit', function(e)` to this ... `$('form#login_form').on('submit', function(e)` just removing the `#` before calling `submit`.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This was helpful thx for sharing.